# Android isn't finding an Inner Class in a Service

Tags: android, mqtt

I cloned a git repo from [here](https://github.com/tokudu/AndroidPushNotificationsDemo) and I tried running it. When I try to launch it, I get a NoClassDef exception.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.tokudu.demo.PushService$MQTTConnection
    at com.tokudu.demo.PushService.connect(PushService.java:280)
    at com.tokudu.demo.PushService.start(PushService.java:242)
    at com.tokudu.demo.PushService.onStart(PushService.java:186)
    at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:458)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2864)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1376)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

It uses an external library, is that what could be causing the problem? `.PushService$MQTTConnection` implements something from said class. I didn't post any code because the linked GitHub is the code I'm using verbatim. I didn't modify it at all (Except trying to make the inner class public instead of private which didn't fix anything.)

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NoClassDefFoundError in Java comes when Java Virtual Machine is not
>   able to find a particular class at runtime which was available during
>   compile time.

Try below few things:

Right Click on your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Order and Export Tab.

Make sure that "Android Private Libraries" is checked for Export.

In case if you see this error despite trying above, this [LINK](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html) has few more tips that you want to try.

Comment: What happens if "Android Private Libraries" isn't an option? [Here](http://i.imgur.com/zpGgz3k.png) is a screenshot. I'm not a novice, I've just never had this problem before. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install the com.ibm.mqtt package. Give it a shot.

Comment: I think I have the Jar as part of the build path. I'll check

Comment: and it is supposed to be present..Right?? did you tried running `Fix Project Properties` and then clean and run app?